# How to List Executable File Names In Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to list all installed applications in windows. Using `powershell` and the following command, I can find out the name and some other details of the installed applications.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ * | Select-Object DisplayName
```

What I want is to also find out the `commandline` of the applications so that I can run the application using that `commandline`. So basically I need following informations-

1. Name of the application
2. Command line of the application
3. Start an application using commandline

What might be the possible solution for doing that?

Answer (score 2):

There are an unfortunately large number of ways to interpret "applications installed" on windows.

If you are looking for a list of programs on your path, you can use

```
Get-Command -Type Application
```

This list includes programs installed as part of Windows, as well as those added after that, if the installer adjusted the PATH environment variable to make the programs visible at the command line.   The list will be big.

Depending on the version of PowerShell you are using, the `Get-Package` command may be of help.   Under PowerShell 5.1, it includes information from multiple sources, including the uninstall programs list in the registry, the windows installer (MSI) database, and information about system updates.  That list will be big too, but different from the `Get-Command` list.

Answer (score 0):

The installed program are located in other registry key:

```
 HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

The following script get all programs and the their commandline:

```
 $q="`""
 Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\*"  |
 Where-Object {$_."(default)" -ne $null} |
 Select-Object @{ expression={$_.PSChildName}; label='Program'} ,@{ expression={$q + $_."(default)" +$q}; label='CommandLine'}
```

Sample of output result:

```
    Program             CommandLine                                                                  
    -------             -----------                                                                  
    7zFM.exe            "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"                                      
    AcroRd32.exe        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"   
    excel.exe           "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office12\EXCEL.EXE"
```